# Overwriting cookies in htaccess

Tags: htaccess, cookie

I run a website in a quite cheap shared hosting environment (LAMP): technically speaking, in this context the only thing I can do is edit one or more `htaccess` files.

Maybe for load balancing purposes, the host serves two unsecure cookies.

Is there any way to set the `Secure` flag on both cookies from an `htaccess` file, overwriting their original values?

Comment: _Aside:_ Any reason these particular cookies _need_ to be secure?

Comment: Good question: this website is https. Sometimes, I submit the website to Mozilla Observatory or other similar websites (securityheaders.io, others related to SSL, etc.). They always report the same defect: an https website is serving unsecure cookies. They see it as a vulnerability, even if probably there's no vulnerability at all in this case. So, this is an "issue" I generally forget, but anytime I find again it I try to solve it, maybe just for curiosity.   :-)

Comment: "They see it as a vulnerability" - That's just a (wild) generalisation. This is a notice/warning at best. Not all cookies should necessarily be "secure" on an HTTPS site (unless perhaps it is HTTPS-only and does not even respond on HTTP). TBH, if this cookie is used for "load balancing" then it probably should not be served with the "secure" flag, otherwise it's not going to be able to "load balance" the HTTP requests - which could be detrimental to server performance. Just as an example, StackOverflow is HTTPS-only and sends 16 cookies, yet only 1 of those cookies has the "secure" flag set.

Comment: There's an online scanner that considers the issue as a "medium" level one. In their own words: "The remote web application sets various cookies throughout a user's unauthenticated and authenticated session. However, there are instances where the application is running over unencrypted HTTP or the cookies are not marked 'secure', meaning the browser could send them back over an unencrypted link under certain circumstances. As a result, it may be possible for a remote attacker to intercept these cookies", "add the secure attribute to all session cookies or any cookies containing sensitive data"

Comment: Another one: "The remote web application sets various cookies throughout a user's unauthenticated and authenticated session. However, one or more of those cookies are not marked 'HttpOnly', meaning that a malicious client-side script, such as JavaScript, could read them. The HttpOnly flag is a security mechanism to protect against cross-site scripting attacks, which was proposed by Microsoft and initially implemented in Internet Explorer. All modern browsers now support it."

Comment: "the browser could send them back over an unencrypted link under certain circumstances" - Although if [you are implementing HSTS](https://serverfault.com/questions/930368/hsts-and-double-redirect) then you are certainly minimising that possibility.

Comment: MrWhite: that's exactly the reason why I implemented it!   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** You probably can't do anything to influence the cookie the *host* is setting "for load balancing purposes".

---

#### Cookie set by application server

If the cookie is being set on your application server, then you can possibly intercept the response and override the `Set-Cookie` HTTP response header.

For example, based on [an answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24246462/369434), the following would unconditionally append the `Secure` flag when setting the cookie "MYCOOKIE" using Apache's mod_headers:

> ```
> Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(MYCOOKIE=.+) "$1; Secure"
> ```

Or, based on [another answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/646227/49157), the following uses a *negative lookahead* to first check that the `Secure` is not already set on the cookie:

> ```
> Header always edit Set-Cookie "(?i)^(MYCOOKIE=(?:(?!;\s?secure).)+)$" "$1; Secure"
> ```

---

#### Cookie set by proxy/load balancer

HOWEVER, if the cookie is being set by a load balancer/proxy that is out of your control then the above method probably won't work. And any attempt to override the cookie may itself get overridden again by the proxy server, depending on when the proxy sets the cookie.

You could try something like the following using mod_rewrite, but bear in mind that you will also need to manually set the *domain* and *path* (and *lifetime*) parts of the cookie exactly the same as they are set by the *host* (eg. by checking the initial `Set-Cookie` HTTP response header you see in the browser), otherwise it won't override the same cookie. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (MYCOOKIE)=([^;]+)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=%1:%2:.example.com:1440:/:secure]
```

`%1` is a backreference to the cookie name (eg. `MYCOOKIE`) in the preceding `RewriteCond` directive. And `%2` is the corresponding value. `.example.com`, `1440` and `/` are the *domain*, *lifetime* (in minutes) and *URL-path* respectively of the cookie that you are trying to set and will need to be set manually.

However, as mentioned above, this may not do anything, as the proxy may simply overwrite this.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried the first of the two ideas with no luck. I try the second but I'm pessimistic   :-)

Comment: Basically I get an error 500 after trying the second one   :-)

Comment: Ah sorry, should be a `=` (not `:`) immediately after the `CO` flag. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, here's no error, but no effect to  :-)  Thanks, anyway!